# Converting day lights savings time string to timestamp gives wrong results

Tags: sql, timezone, apache-spark-sql, dst, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a `pyspark` data frame. In this data frame I have a column called `test_time` which is of `string` datatype

```
>>> df
DataFrame[test_time: string]
```

`df.show()`

```
+-------------------+
|          test_time|
+-------------------+
|2017-03-12 02:41:06|
|2017-03-12 02:43:52|
|2017-03-12 02:56:32|
|2017-03-12 03:16:23|
|2017-03-12 03:17:15|
|2017-03-12 03:22:19|
|2017-03-12 03:52:19|
|2017-03-12 04:03:21|
+-------------------+
```

Now I want to convert this `test_time` column from `string` to `timestamp`

I have done like below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = df.withColumn('convert_test', F.unix_timestamp('test_time', "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").cast('timestamp'))

>>> df1
DataFrame[test_time: string, convert_test: timestamp]

df1.show()

+-------------------+--------------------+
|          test_time|        convert_test|
+-------------------+--------------------+
|2017-03-12 02:41:06|2017-03-12 03:41:...|
|2017-03-12 02:43:52|2017-03-12 03:43:...|
|2017-03-12 02:56:32|2017-03-12 03:56:...|
|2017-03-12 03:16:23|2017-03-12 03:16:...|
|2017-03-12 03:17:15|2017-03-12 03:17:...|
|2017-03-12 03:22:19|2017-03-12 03:22:...|
|2017-03-12 03:52:19|2017-03-12 03:52:...|
|2017-03-12 04:03:21|2017-03-12 04:03:...|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

As you can see the `Hours`  are different for rows `1-3`.

`FYI`  my timezone is `PST` and the rows `1-3` are timings during `day light savings` time.

How can I get the correct conversion to be done.

Comment: Your data looks wrong.  If timeone is PST, then there should be correction then on 02:00:00 clocks should be moved forward to 03:00:00 and you should never get `02:41:06`. In that case conversion local TZ -> UTC -> local TZ sounds like something undefined, but I definitely wouldn't expect to see `2017-03-12 02:41:06`. I am not timezone expert though... :)

Comment: @user6910411 The data is from a `mysql` table where I got the `timestamp` column as a `string`. The data is correct

Comment: My point is - you exported data without considering daylight savings, but read it in a system configured to correct for daylight savings. If your clock would be set to `America/Los_Angeles` (seems like equivalent to your current settings) you wouldn't experience `02:41` in the first place. But like said, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the correct output with `unix_timestamp()`

```
  val dataframe = Seq(
    ("2017-03-12 02:41:06"),
    ("2017-03-12 02:43:52"),
    ("2017-03-12 02:56:32"),
    ("2017-03-12 03:16:23"),
    ("2017-03-12 03:17:15"),
    ("2017-03-12 03:22:19"),
    ("2017-03-12 03:52:19"),
    ("2017-03-12 04:03:21")
  ).toDF("test_time")

 dataframe.withColumn("convert_test", unix_timestamp($"test_time", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").cast("timestamp")).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+
|          test_time|        convert_test|
+-------------------+--------------------+
|2017-03-12 02:41:06|2017-03-12 02:41:...|
|2017-03-12 02:43:52|2017-03-12 02:43:...|
|2017-03-12 02:56:32|2017-03-12 02:56:...|
|2017-03-12 03:16:23|2017-03-12 03:16:...|
|2017-03-12 03:17:15|2017-03-12 03:17:...|
|2017-03-12 03:22:19|2017-03-12 03:22:...|
|2017-03-12 03:52:19|2017-03-12 03:52:...|
|2017-03-12 04:03:21|2017-03-12 04:03:...|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

If you have in different timezone than you can use function like `from_utc_timestamp()` and `to_utc_timestamp()` to convert the timestamp.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: So did you try converting from utc to PST